# Tidy URLs in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, duplicate-content, canonical-url

My Google Analytics is catching a number of URLs where there is a unique GET parameter.

It also catches URLs like `/pay` and `/pay/`.

Is there any way I can get it to clean up the data and just see tidy page views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got to the page with `/pay` does it load or redirect to `/pay/`?

When editing your profile you can tell GA to [exclude some query parameters](http://cutroni.com/blog/2006/09/21/google-analytics-configuration-mistake-2-query-string-variables/)

> To force GA to skip certain query string parameters when processing we
>   enter the unwanted parameters in the ‘Exclude URL Query Parameters:’
>   filed in the ‘Main Website Profile Information’ section.

Comment: Both `/pay` and /`pay/` show the same content.  Will try the Exclude settings.

Comment: There are also advanced filters which you can use in Analytics

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with trailing slashes, as `/pay` and `/pay/` [will be treated as two different pages](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html) and you may be penalized for duplicate content.

I think the issue is more about tidying up the URLs to make sure there is a trailing slash.

Add the following code to your .htaccess file to add a trailing slash to all URLs. It is also useful to include a [canonical link](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) on all of your pages to help eliminate potential duplicate issues.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)([^/])$ http://example.org/$1$2/ [R=301,L]
```